# How to get the value of a textbox inside a <td> using the id of <tr> in jquery

Tags: jquery

i have a table like this

```
<table>
<tr id ='1tr'>
<td><input type='textbox' value='1'></td>
 <td><input type='textbox' value='2'></td>
 </tr> 
 <tr id ='2tr'>
  <td><input type='textbox' value='3'></td>
  <td><input type='textbox' value='4'></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

how i can get the value of text box in second td that is in tr with id 2tr

Comment: you want td value or textbox value?

Comment: maybe read the docs a bit, this is standard css selector syntax...

Comment: There is no textbox in tr with id '1'!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$('#1 input').val();​
```

New code after your edit in your answer

```
$('#2tr td:eq(1) input').val();
```

is what you want?

Comment: That returns "value", not the value from the text box. There is no text box in the tr "with id1", so the OP naturally means id 2.

Comment: If that td contains two input fields, how i can get it separately?

Comment: I think that you can use something like: input:eq(0) for the first input. But I can't try now

Answer (score 1):

There is no textbox in tr with id '1', so I guess you wnat this one out of tr with id '2'...

You can write:

```
$('#2 td input').val()
```

But it is not recommended to use number as ID in an HTML-DOM!

Answer (score 0):

That would be:

```
$('#2 input').val()
```

If your code is more complex than your example, you may need to make the selector more specific, for example:

```
$('#2 > td > input[type=text]').val()
```

Note that you should avoid using numbers as id. That causes problems in some situations.

Also note that the type should be `text`, not `textbox`:

```
<input type='text' value='1'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$('#1 input[type="text"]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('table tr input').val()


$('#2 input').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use this way.

Here i'm have acces to each txttexboxname and get the value

```
$("#tablename input[name='txttexboxname']").each(function(indice){
    alert($(this).val()) //show the value
    alert($("#tablename [id='txttexboxname']:eq("+(index)+")").val()) //show the value
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.